# Limit of a Sequence with Function - Proof Verification

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, solution-verification

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$ and let $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ be a differentiable function, let $t \in [a,b]$, and consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_1=t & \\ 
x_{n+1}=f(x_n) & \forall n\geq 1 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Now, suppose that there exists a point $\alpha \in [a,b]$ such that $f(\alpha)=\alpha$.

Let $0 \le q <1$ such that $|f'(x)|\le q$ for every $x \in [a,b]$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=\alpha$

The above I have successfully proved, with some of your help!

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$, and the sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_0=y & \\ 
x_{n+1}=\cos(x_n) & \forall n\geq 0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Prove that the sequence converge to a limit $0<\alpha<1$.

So I wanted to establish on the first half of the question:

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be defined as $f(x)=\cos(x)$.

By the fixed point, there exists an $\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha)=\alpha$

Notice that $f'(x)=-\sin(x)$ and for every $x \in [0,1]$ we have $0 \le \sin(x) < 1$,

So there exists a $0 \le q < 1$ such that $|f'(x) \le q|$ for every $x \in [0,1]$.

Notice that $f(x_n)=\cos(x_n)=x_{n+1}$.

$x_0=y \to x_1=\cos(y) \to 0 \le x_1 \le 1 \to x_1 \in[0,1]$

Define $t=x_1$.

Define  $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_1=t & \\ 
x_{n+1}=f(x_n) & \forall n\geq 1 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

So we get, by the first half: $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=\alpha$.

My only problem here is that I proved it for $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and not $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$.

Any help on how to complete my proof?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$$ is independent of what the first element of the sequence is. It is, in fact, independent of the first **finitely many** elements of the sequence.

To say the same thing more strictly, it's relatively easy (and also good practice!) to prove the following:

> Let $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ and let $(y_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be two sequences that differ only on a finitely many number of elements. Then, the two sequences are either both divergent or both convergent. Furthermore, if they are convergent, their limits are the same.

The above statement can be proven directly from the definition of limits (i.e. the one with the epsilons), and uses the fact that there must exist some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n>N$, you have $x_n=y_n$.

Comment: Alright cool! So except the theorem I need to prove, everything looks ok to you? Thanks!

Comment: @MathLover No, actually. You don't have $f'(x)\leq q < 1$ if $f(x)=\cos(x)$.

Comment: Why not? $|f'(x)|=\sin(x)$ and for every $0 \le x \le 1$ we have $0 \le \sin(x) < 1$, so for $0 \le q < 1$ we have $|f'(x)|=|\sin(x)| \le q$

Comment: @MathLover There does not exist any $q$ for which $f'(x)\leq q < 1$ is true *for all $x$*. The theorem demands that the number $q$ is *independent* of $x$. That is, you get to pick one $q$, and that one value of $q$ must satisfy the condition for all values of $x$. In your case, such a $q$ does not exist.

Comment: @MathLover That is, unless you can define $a$ and $b$ appropriately. Hint hint.